# How does TensorFlow differentiate over Gaussian parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

When using variational autoencoders it is common to use stochastic tensors after the encoder that will have any value sampled from a distribution (Gaussian, Bernoulli, ...). How does Tensorflow calculate the derivatives with respect to the distribution parameters in order to do backpropagation?

**Note:** I know how to differentiate using Tensorflow API. I would like to know how it calculates the derivative internally, in other words, how could I do it using pen and paper?

Thanks!